# cant see the errors in my project - Exclamation mark

Tags: eclipse

When I'm trying to run my project it said that i have an errors in my project, but i can't see any. I have an Exclamation mark on my project. If I'm trying to run other project, it is run perfectly.
Before that happened, I played a little bit with the project library and tried to copy some jars to the library. I tried to copy the jars manual to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try the "Problems" View? This should show additional information.
The easiest Way to get there:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>, then type "Problems".

-Hannes

Comment: Thanks, that helped! In the problems view it said that the project is missing required library: at it give me a path to the to jars I tried to add. Do you know what should I do?

Comment: Maybe add the required jars as external libraries.
Right click your project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries

Answer (score 0):

Besides the "Problems" view, there is also the Console that could give you some hints.

For the Console View, there is the problem that it can show different subviews; for example it can show the console for Android or the console for DDMS.  In the toolbar at the upper right of the Console view, you will find the control to choose the right console to display.  Be sure to choose the "Android Console".

Another possibility is to use the "Fix Project Properties" that you will find by right clicking on the projet => Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties.  This will fixes some but not all the potential problems that you might have introduced in your project.

For the rest, check in detail all properties of the project.